# Rails gem Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

There is gem [country-state-select](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select), I have to fork as gem was not maintained & required few custom changes. made changes & pushed code.

than in gem file used

```
gem "country_state_select", "~> 3.1", :github => 'Faisal-nfl/Country-State-Select', :branch => 'faisal-dev'
```

Data for country-state-select gem is populated by [city-state](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state) gem.

Everything was working fine on local machine, But when deployed on the server its giving error as

> **Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/deploy/kids/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/city-state-0.0.13/lib/db/states.us**

It looks like a common issue as clear from [issues](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state/issues/3)

But didn't see any proper solution.
How to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe You need to give that folder permission. Use sudo chmod 777 *

Comment: This might work but than I have to do it with each deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/deploy/kids/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/*`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and this solution work for me:

```
$gem which city-state 

-> /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/city-state-0.0.13/lib/city-state.rb


$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/*
```